# Is there any tangible benefit of limiting a password to 12 characters?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

Among the password requirements in this form, there's a minimum length of 8 characters (fine), but a *maximum* length of 12:

[image: 8-12 character password limit form]

Before just dismissing this as incompetence, is there anything I'm missing here as to why this might be an even vaguely good idea?

Comment: I think you're correct in your first assumption, in that no-one really thought it was necessary and is distinctly arbitrary.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22884/my-credit-union-is-reducing-its-maximum-password-length-to-10-characters?rq=1 ?